# Accessing data from HttpListener in WinForms as we do with ASP .NET (Request["Key"])

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, httplistener

In a **WinForms** application targeting .NET 4, I am using the WebClient.UploadValues(Uri, "POST", NameValueCollection) to send values to an instance of HttpListener. On the listener side, when the HttpListener.GetContext() method returns, I can access the sent data as a byte [].

I can convert this data to text using EncodingXXX.GetString(buffer) which returns the following:

- Key1=Value1
- Key2=Value2
- **...**

Each item in the string is delimited by the ampersand sign `&`. I have to manually split the data into pairs and further split the pairs into keys and values.

I'd like to know if the same data can be accessed similar to ASP .NET WebForms (var value = this.Form["Key"])? Of course, I know we don't have the WebForms context here but I'd prefer to use existing infrastructure for this kind of processing wherever possible.

Comment: Great question, but can you not use [OWIN](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) to run an ASP.NET Web Application in the Windows Forms project itself? This totally doesn't answer your question, but it might be a better way to do what it sounds like you want to. Just food for thought.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: Thanks. That may be suited for some situations but in my case, the WinForms app is a simple test application for the library that contains custom request/response and http listener classes. Hosting a web app would be overkill here.

Comment: Fair enough. Yeah, I just wanted to make sure you weren't overlooking the simple solution, if you were actually doing a more complicated project.

Comment: Great suggestion though. I did not know about OWIN and will certainly try it out for other projects. Not sure how comprehensive it is but sounds like a great tool for web app demos (if it eliminates IIS configuration on the client machines).

Comment: Yeah, definitely. It's built into any new ASP projects you make in VS 2013 by default, I believe, so it shouldn't be *too* complicated to use like that, although admittedly I've never done anything with self-hosting like I suggested.

Comment: As for your question, do you think [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) would work? It was my initial thought, and I wrote it off at first. But thinking now, the fact that you're looking at forms shouldn't make any difference. Anything valid in a query should be valid in a form, right?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: Thanks, I'll try that out and revert back but you should definitely post this as an answer. It returns a NameValueCollection which is the closest to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, I'm posting this as an answer.

I believe it should work in all cases, let me know if it doesn't, but [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) should be a perfect match for this.

It is, as is suggested by the name, meant for parsing URL query strings, but from what I can think, it should be a clean conversion from anything that's permissible in a datastring to anything that's permissible in a URL (of course, not vice-versa).

Comment: Your suggestion works so marking the answer as correct. On an unrelated note, now that I think about it, it worries me that the data is being posted as a delimited list of key/pair values in the first place (due to `WebClient.UploadValues`). I'm considering uploading an xml container instead using `UploadString` or `UploadData`.

Comment: If you're talking from a client to an API, yes, I would use XML or JSON. I'm sure there are questions and even papers about this, but I tend to view using forms as an outdated technique that's supported because websites already use it. Like, if we could restart the internet right now knowing what we do, I think we'd switch over to HTML `form`s using formatted data like that. It's just a matter of backwards compatibility that grandfathers in this method. But again, I could be wrong. It's just a hunch. But that's the impression I get.